# How can PHP code be made aware of specific class subtypes passed to it, when using polymorphism?

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism, dynamic-typing

I have a class called `Assembly` that hides implementation of underlying products.  `ProductA` can have one set of getters, `ProductB` can have another.

While PHP is quite forgiving and if I don't mix up Products and getters, my code will work, but there is no protection offered for when I do mess up and populate `Assembly` with `ProductA`, but then use a getter from `ProductB`.

Also, my IDE does know the methods from either class, so there is no auto-complete offered when I work inside `Assembly` with getters from either `Product`.

I want more bullet-proof code, one where `Assembly` *knows* or *is aware of* which `Product` subtype it currently hosts.  Is there a way to do so?

Sample below

```php
class Assembly
{
    private $product;

    public function setProduct(Product $product) {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function getA() {
        return $this->product->getA();
    }

    public function getB() {
        return $this->product->getB();
    }
}

class Product { }

class ProductA extends Product
{
    public function getA() {
        return "A";
    }
}

class ProductB extends Product
{
    public function getB() {
        return "B";
    }
}

//set assembly
$assembly = new Assembly();

//define product sub-type
$product = new ProductB();

//place product into assembly
$assembly->setProduct($product);

//assembly has no clue which subtype it has 
print $assembly->getB(); // "B"
print $assembly->getA(); // prints nothing
```

**Interface Suggestion**

```
interface CompositeProductInterface
{
    public function getA();
    public function getB();
}

//update code in Assembly to:
public function setProduct(CompositeProductInterface $product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}
```

This gives me autocomplete in my IDE, which is nice, but doesn't solve my other issues.  Also I am a little eerie on mushing things together into a single "composite" product.... It seems more like a work-around.  In my specific case I have two very similar products that differ on some minute things like a few properties.

**Real World Example**

Both Product models A and B have an engineering drawing that lists variables to identify various product dimensions.  Named dimensions are similar across both products.  For example, M1 on product A means the same physical dimension on product B.  However, Product A has features not present on product B and vice versa.

If that still feels too hypothetical, the actual dimensions on the actual drawing are listed as *B2*, and *B3*.  These dimensions (B2, B3) are not present on the other product model.  I want to be able go use an assembly construct to list variables on the drawing, including M1, B2, B3, and so on.   I could do so with

```
print $assembly->getM1(); //works for both products
print $assembly->getB2(); //works for one product only
print $assembly->getB3(); //same as above
```

**Goal**

Goal is to have a single class (assembly) responsible for listing named dimension variables, and each product only know itself.  So

- Assembly says "I know everything about the named variables I want to list (M1, B2, B3), regardless of product model"
- Product A says "I only know what I contain.  I contain named dimension A.  I don't know what B is nor do I care to
- Product B says "I only know B"
  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not feel this is the right solution, but what you ask for could be achieved in the following way.

```
get_class($product);
```

Will tell you which class `$product` is. Which would lead to the following code:

```
private $product;
private $productClass;

public function setProduct(Product $product) {
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->productClass = get_class($product);
}
```

Or:

```
public function getProductClass(){
    return get_class($this->$product);
}
```

Which could leads to a check similar to:

```
public function getA() {
    if($this->productClass === "ProductA")
        return $this->product->getA();
}
```

As well documented in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

Comment: cool.  you can also use `ProductA::class` construct instead of `"ProductA"` with benefit of type hinting by IDE/PHP interpreter

Comment: Is a way better solution to the comparasion.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already an accepted answer but I would like to give a more correct OOP approach.

The actual solution will work only because PHP use the real type and does not restrict the scope of the object from the method signature type.

To avoid complexity divergence I wouldn't recommend a code where you must add some code in a class (your assembly) each time you add another one (a new product type).

---

In your case, I would use a [pattern adapter](http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern).

Here your adapters:

```
interface AssemblyInterface 
{
    function getA();
    function getB();
}

class AssemblyA implements AssemblyInterface
{
    private $product;

    public function setProduct(ProductA $product) {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function getA() {
        return $this->product->getA();
    }

    public function getB() {
        return;
    }
}

class AssemblyB implements AssemblyInterface
{
    private $product;

    public function setProduct(ProductB $product) {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function getA() {
        return;
    }

    public function getB() {
        return $this->product->getB();
    }
}
```

Here your adaptees:

```
class ProductA
{
    public function getA() {
        return "A";
    }
}

class ProductB
{
    public function getB() {
        return "B";
    }
}
```

Now, you can use a [pattern factory](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern) to retrieve your assemblies.

Here your creators:

```
interface AssemblyCreatorInterface
{
    function isSupportingProduct($product);
    function createAssembly($product);
}

class AssemblyCreatorA implements AssemblyCreatorInterface
{
    public function isSupportingProduct($product) {
        return $product instanceof ProductA;
    }

    public function createAssembly($product) {
        return new AssemblyA($product);
    }
}

class AssemblyCreatorB implements AssemblyCreatorInterface
{
    public function isSupportingProduct($product) {
        return $product instanceof ProductB;
    }

    public function createAssembly($product) {
        return new AssemblyB($product);
    }
}
```

Here you assembly factory:

```
class AssemblyFactory
{
    private $assemblyCreators = array();

    public function addCreator(AssemblyCreatorInterface $assemblyCreator) {
        $this->assemblyCreators = $assemblyCreator;
    }

    public function get($product) {
        // Find the good creator for your product.
        foreach ($this->assemblyCreators as $assemblyCreator) {
            if ($assemblyCreator->isSupportingProduct($product)) {
                // Create and return the assembly for your product.
                return $assemblyCreator->createAssembly($product);
            }
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
            'No available assembly creator for product "".',
            get_class($product);
        ));
    }
}
```

Finally, here is a program example:

```
// Process dependency injection.
// (you should be able to do it only once in your code)
$assemblyCreatorA = new AssemblyCreatorA();
$assemblyCreatorB = new AssemblyCreatorB();

$assemblyFactory = new AssemblyFactory();
$assemblyFactory->addCreator($assemblyCreatorA);
$assemblyFactory->addCreator($assemblyCreatorB);

// Retrieve assemblies from products.
$productA = new ProductA();
$productB = new ProductB();

$assemblyA = $assemblyFactory->get($productA);
$assemblyB = $assemblyFactory->get($productB);

$assemblyA->getA(); // 'A'
$assemblyA->getB(); // null
$assemblyB->getA(); // null
$assemblyB->getB(); // 'B'
```

---

This is a bit more code but this respects your method signatures and will handle the growing complexity of your application. With this solution, if you have 100 different product types, each one will be independent from others (one class `Assembly`, one class `Product` and one class `Creator`). Imagine your assembly class if you must code the specificity of each product for each getter in it!